# How to return a "text" in css less?

Tags: css, less

How can I do something like this:?

```
.test1(@light: 1px;){
    "inset 0 @light 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)";
}
.test2(@elevation: 3px;){
    "0 @elevation 0 rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.1)";
}

@testing: .test1() "," .test2(); 
box-shadow: @testing;
```

Comment: LESS does not support this; you can't make your own functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the following approach:

```
// Box shadow.
.mx-box-sh (@arguments) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: @arguments;
     -moz-box-shadow: @arguments;
          box-shadow: @arguments;
}

// Mixin for your specific needs.
.mx-my-box-sh (@light: 1px, @elevation: 3px) {
  .mx-box-sh(e(%("inset 0 %s 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 %s 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)", @light, @elevation)));
}

// Call the mixin.
.my-selector {
  .mx-my-box-sh();
}
```

Make sure you’re using the latest LESS compiler (1.4.0).

As much as I’m aware, you can’t “return” text from mixins. Mixins are, in fact, procedural constructs that don’t return anything whatsoever.